# Why can't I comment on Meta?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, meta, browser-cache

I can still post comments on regular SO, but suddenly comments on Meta won't work. The button to add a comment is there, and I click it, and nothing happens. Same thing when a post has too many comments to see and I click "see X more comments" - nothing happens. Is it just me, or is this hitting anyone else?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: @Chris Lutz I've been having issues over the past few days with Meta (and with STack Overflow in general) where I can't post a comment, or vote, or vote on a comment without refreshing the page. If I refresh the page, it starts working again.

Comment: This was happening on multiple pages. I believe I tried refreshing at one point, though (it seems like something I would have done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a local javascript issue. Works fine for me and no one else has reported any issues with it so far.  Maybe check your browser settings and restart the browser? Most likely some type of javascript error. You running any no script plugin?

Comment: No no-script plugins. I quit and restarted Firefox and it works now (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in Opera for a few months now.

Comment: You've cleared your cache and you don't have `sstatic.net` blocked?

Comment: Yup. Still have this problem in Opera.